# Azure DevOps Release pipeline Azure subscription field is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a release pipeline in my Azure DevOps account to deploy my site to a dev/test/prod environment. I Already set up the service connection and is working ok. When I am creating the pipeline and use for example the "Deploy Azure App Service" template the task option for "Azure Subscription" is disabled and I can't select my already configured connection.

[image: Task Option field disabled]

I know everything is ok because I already tested the connection using a build yaml pipeline with the task "AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4" and the deploy process using the connection was successful.

[image: yaml with the task successful connected]

Is there a way the option become available so I can use it in a release pipeline?

Comment: Can you please check in your Stage if any Azure Subscription parameter is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the Azure subscription in the tasks, navigate to the Stage section and click on "**Unlink All**" in the Parameters option as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Next, proceed to the Azure App Service Deploy task and verify that the Azure subscription is now enabled.

[image]